# shell script : search a word in a file linewise

Tags: shell

i want to search a word from a file and display total number of occurrence of that word line wise. what i  know to solve this , is that grep command :

```
echo "enter a word to search"
read word
echo "enter file name"
read file

grep $word $file
```

that's all i know but i don't know how to print total occurrence and line wise occurrence of that word.
how can i do that ? here is sampled output

```
file content
hello world in shell script 
hello world in hello script 
hello , hello world in hello script
```

expected output

```
enter word to search = hello
total occurrence 6
line 1 occurrence 1
line 2 occurrence 2
line 3 occurrence 3
```

one more thing , i know about counting words . `wc -w $filename` . but i don't know how to count that specific word.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk '
BEGIN {
    printf "Enter a word to search: "
    getline word < "-"
}
{
line[NR] = gsub(word,"");
sum+=line[NR]
}
END {
print "total occurrence " sum;
for(i=1;i<=NR;i++)
    print "line " i " occurence " line[i]
}' inputfile

Enter a word to search: hello
total occurrence 7
line 1 occurence 1
line 2 occurence 2
line 3 occurence 3
```

Orginal answer:

```
$ awk '{print "line " NR " occurrence " gsub("hello","")}' inputfile

line 1 occurrence 1
line 2 occurrence 2
line 3 occurrence 3
```

Comment: +1; clever and fast; takes advantage of the fact that `gsub()` returns the number of replacements; total is missing, and passing in the search term as a variable might be nice.

Answer (score 1):

please use this option

grep -n "keyword" "filename"

Answer (score 0):

```
# Sample search term.
word='hello'

# Loop over all input lines; assumes input filename is `file`.
totalCount=0 counts=() # initialize variables
while IFS= read -r line; do
  # Count the occurrence of the search term on the current line.
  # `grep -o` outputs each occurrence on a separate line, so
  # by counting the output lines we know the occurrence count.
  count=$(grep -o "$word" <<<"$line" | wc -l)
      # Add to the output array of per-line occurrence counts.
  counts+=( $count )
      # Update the overall count.
  (( totalCount+= count ))
done < file

# Output
  # Total count.
echo "total occurence $totalCount"
  # Loop over the array with all per-line occurrence counts and 
  # output each.
for (( i = 1; i <= ${#counts[@]}; i++ )); do
  echo "line $i occurrences ${counts[i-1]}"
done
```